# AEM (cq5) smartimage drop target allowed

Tags: aem

Is there any way to set up the smartimage to only accept certain type of files in drag and drop? I noticed there is information for uploading

> mimeTypes : String MIME types allowed for uploading (each separated by
>   a semicolon; wildcard * is allowed; for example: "*.*" or
>   "*.jpg;*.gif;*.png". Defaults to "*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png".

However there is no information about allowing only specific file types for drag and drop. I have team members that are uploading PSD images which work on the Image preview tab but the source saved into the jcr is the actual file ".png".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the ddAccept parameter to lock down specific mime types only for drag and drop.

```
ddAccept : String MIME type definition of files that are allowed for referencing using drag & drop (defaults to "image/")
```

http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/ref/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.form.SmartImage

Since the system defaults to "image/", then it's probably allowing PSD images because their mime type is "image/vnd.adobe.photoshop".

Maybe try to set the ddAccept property to the same as mimeTypes and see if that works:

```
"*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png"
```

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation I have tried different ways of assigning the right parameter to ddAccept and none is taken. All the strings I provide end up locking the drag and drop area. Not that ddAccept is not what needs to be used but it is what I am currently facing. I will report back if things change.